# Change CSS attribute with TypeScript and Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, function

I want to change the `z-index` CSS attribute from the `<footer>` when `<select>` is open, but i don't know how to do it on TypeScript (Angular 10). The footer already have `z-index: 9998;` but i want to set it to `0;`. The reason is because when my select is open, the options go under the footer and the user can't really choose.

```js
$('.test').on('click', () => {
  $('footer').css('z-index', '0');
})
```

```html
<select
  class="test"
  placeholder="select an option"
  formControlname="bank">
  
  <option> 1 </option>
  <option> 2 </option>
  <option> 3 </option>
  <option> 4 </option>
  
</select>
```

Comment: Add some code and show us what you did?

Comment: Hey! I can't use the actual code because of corporate stuff and we use an private design system, but it's basically the code i added now. Tried to change through JQuery, but didn't work.

Comment: This looks more of just a css issue. Give a higher z-index for the select box in css. Say z-index: 9999;

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work either.

Comment: We have an HTML `<select>` attribute that calls selectOpen, that expects an method with event when select is open, but i don't know how i could use the method for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, it works just fine as soon as you click the select. The footer z-index is set to 0.
Make sure you are importing jquery in your code.

```js
$('.test').on('click', () => {
  $('footer').css('z-index', '0');
})
```

```css
footer {
  z-index: 9998;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test" placeholder="select an option" formControlname="bank">

  <option> 1 </option>
  <option> 2 </option>
  <option> 3 </option>
  <option> 4 </option>

</select>

<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna try an similar solution, but i gotta wait to see if that's gonna work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the other answer. He answered using jQuery. You should *never* directly manipulate the DOM when using Angular.

There is no way to react directly to it being opened and closed. That is because it can be opened by means other than clicking on it. For instance, if the `<select>` element is focused and then the user hits enter, the dropdown will open but the `click` event will not be fired.

What you are asking for can be achieved using custom components that can be found online however. I personally would recommend this one: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

Comment: Thank you for your input @michael-ziluck. However, I have simply built on the code that he posted. That way the answer will be the closest to what he wants. We all agree that it is not optimal. The answer is only to help inspire him for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, man! I removed the "on click" property and created a function with only `$(footer).css('z-index', '0');` . I can't use custom components because it's an corporate application,  but the component that we use have selectOpen property that when the select is open we can make it do something. I don't know if that's gonna work, was hoping an TypeScript solution. But thanks, i'm gonna wait to see if it will work.